# Why can't I add a node to linked list in C?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

I have a problem with linked lists in C. I made a function that created a new node of the list with some information (char *description) and added it to its end. The code is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node {
     char *description;
     struct node *next;
};


// The function to create a node and append it to the linked list of nodes

struct node* create_node(struct node *first, char *description) {
     struct node *current = first;

     // Iteration through the list until the end
     while(current != NULL) {
         node++;
         current = current -> next;
     }

     // Now pointer current points at the end of the list, first -> next. How to assign the pointer new to first -> next through current?

     struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(struct container));

     new -> next = NULL;
     new -> description = malloc(sizeof(description));

     memcpy(new -> description, description, sizeof(description));

     current = new;
     return current;
}

int main() {
     // Creating the first node
     struct node *first = create_node(NULL, "First");

     // Creating and appending the second node to the list 
     create_node(first, "Second");


     printf("%d\n", first -> next == NULL); // Prints 1, the newly created node hasn't been appended

     return 0;
}
```

I searched how to create the list of the kind and saw very similar ways of how to do it. I know that it's something basic and most likely there's a simple solution, but I can't find it.
Thanks everyone for respond.

Comment: @M.T. Where is struct container defined?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry, I meant struct node : )

Comment: I see a few problems.  One is, I see `node++;`, is `node` a global?  But more to the point, the new node isn't linked into the list.  In order to do so, it needs to change the `next` pointer of the last list element to point to the new element.  It doesn't do this.  Also, the first loop iterates until `current` is `NULL`.  It's no different from just assigning `NULL` to `current`.  It doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: @M.T. Make sure that your code compiles and state expected and actual behavior.

Comment: This is also wrong:  `malloc(sizeof(description))`  But `description` is a pointer, so its size is fixed and ignores how long the string is.  You need `malloc(strlen(description) + 1)`  The `+1` is for the null byte at the end.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you for respond. How can I find the end of the list in other way? Also how to change it to the newly created element?

Comment: To find the last element of the list, you need to stop *before* `current` becomes `NULL`.  Stop when `current->next` is `NULL`.  But you need to add a check for `first == NULL` and skip the loop in that case, which makes sense since in that case there is no last node to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function name `create_node` is confusing. It is much better to name the function at least like `append_node`.

The second function parameter should have the qualifier const because the passed string is not changed in the function.

In these statements

```
 new -> description = malloc(sizeof(description));
 memcpy(new -> description, description, sizeof(description));
```

you are allocating memory of the size equal either to 8 or to 4 bytes depending on the value of `sizeof( char * )` and correspondingly coping this number of bytes.

You have at least to write

```
 new -> description = malloc( strlen(description));
 memcpy(new -> description, description, strlen(description));
```

But it would be better if you were copying the whole string.

The function has a bug. It does not append a node to the list because within the function there is changed the local pointer current that is not chained to the list.

Take into account that memory allocation can fail. You should process such a situation.

The function can be safer and simpler if to pass the pointer to the head node by reference.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    char *description;
    struct node *next;
};


// The function to create a node and append it to the linked list of nodes

int append_node( struct node **head, const char *description ) 
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->description = malloc( strlen( description ) + 1 );
        success = new_node->description != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            strcpy( new_node->description, description );
            new_node->next = NULL;

            while ( *head != NULL )
            {
                head = &( *head )->next;
            }

            *head = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            free( new_node );
        }
    }

    return success; 
}

int main( void ) 
{
    // Creating the first node
    struct node *head = NULL;

    if ( append_node( &head, "first" ) )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", head->description );
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
first
```

Comment: Hi just want to thank u for the answer. u just saved my project. I had been stuck on for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am new at this community. Lets try to help.

I thik you are pointing to the last node of the list and changing it to the new one at line

```
current = new;
```

But to link the new node you should save it in the field next of the node, try:

```
current->next=new;
```

I hope help you, bye :).

Comment: It is a bad advice because current is equal to NULL.:)

Comment: yeah that is the idea it is pointing to NULL you make it point to new then new  is going to point NULL.

Comment: assignments like something pointing to NULL=something are allowed but NULL=something is not allowed just try to do current->next=new; it should work